# Problema carácter con tildes o Ñ base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo un problema con los caracteres tildados y las Ñ, figuran de la siguiente manera en la base de datos;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El sistema lee un archivo de texto o cvs delitimato por comas con javascript;

```
/*  Leer archivo */
function leerArchivo( e ) {
    var archivo = e.target.files[ 0 ];
    if ( !archivo ) {
        return;
    }
    var lector = new FileReader();
    lector.onload = function ( e ) {
        var contenido = e.target.result;
        mostrarContenido( contenido );
    };
    lector.readAsText( archivo );
}

function mostrarContenido( contenido ) {
    var filename = $("#documento_texto").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
    var extencion_archivo_cargado = filename.slice(filename.length-3);
    if(extencion_archivo_cargado === "txt" || extencion_archivo_cargado === "csv" ){

    }else{
        alert("Solo se aceptan archivo de texto plano (txt) o csv.");
        return; //detener la ejecucion
    }       

    $("#tablas_datos_procesados").fadeOut(500).removeAttr("hidden");
    $("body").append('');
    //utilizando el contenido del array creado por el archivo       
    var longitud_contenido_archivo = contenido.length;
    var archivo = new Array(); 
    /* Elementos de la tabla*/

    var tr = " ";
    //mostrar_archivo_pagina.innerHTML = contenido;
    for ( var i = 0; i < longitud_contenido_archivo; i++ ) {

        //Forzando a tener un valor a las variables
            archivo.descripcion = "undefined";
            archivo.punto_suministro = "undefined";
            archivo.fne = "undefined";
            archivo.erkwh = "undefined";
            archivo.verrd = "undefined";
            archivo.fnp = "undefined";
            archivo.fecha = "undefined";

        if(contenido[i].indexOf(",") == 0 || i == 0){
            //i++; /* se incrementa en 1 antes de entrar al ciclo de lo contrario jamas entrar ya que dara 0 el resultado porque si encontro la coma*/
            while(contenido[i].indexOf(",") != 0){archivo.id_archivo += contenido[ i++ ];}
            i++; while(contenido[i].indexOf(",") != 0){archivo.descripcion += contenido[ i++ ];}
            i++; while(contenido[i].indexOf(",") != 0){archivo.punto_suministro += contenido[ i++ ];}
            i++; while(contenido[i].indexOf(",") != 0){archivo.fne += contenido[ i++ ];}
            i++; while(contenido[i].indexOf(",") != 0){archivo.erkwh += contenido[ i++ ];}
            i++; while(contenido[i].indexOf(",") != 0){archivo.verrd += contenido[ i++ ];}
            i++; while(contenido[i].indexOf(",") != 0){archivo.fnp += contenido[ i++ ];}
            i++; while(contenido[i].indexOf(",") != 0){archivo.fecha += contenido[ i++ ];}

                //Insertando datos en la bd
                /* AJAX */
                (function insertar_registro () {
                    var resultado = document.getElementById("div_numero_procesado");                        
                    var xmlhttp;

                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                            resultado.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText; //Escribiendo todas las respuestas del servidor
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/ajax/insertar_registro.php", true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xmlhttp.send('descripcion=' + archivo.descripcion.slice(9) + 
                        '&punto_suministro=' + archivo.punto_suministro.slice(9) + 
                        '&fne=' + archivo.fne.slice(9) + 
                        '&erkwh=' + archivo.erkwh.slice(9) + 
                        '&verrd=' + archivo.verrd.slice(9) + 
                        '&fnp=' + archivo.fnp.slice(9) + 
                        '&fecha=' + archivo.fecha.slice(9));
                }());                   


            //Limpiando variables para usarlas nuevamente
            for (var valores_del_archivo in archivo) {
                archivo[valores_del_archivo] = "undefined";
            }           

        } //Fin del if principal        

    }//Fin del for principa         
    $("#div_archivo").toggle(500).prop("hidden","true");
}//fin de la funcion

document.getElementById( 'documento_texto' ).addEventListener( 'change', leerArchivo, false );

    });
```

Posteriormente es enviado con ajax al archivo php;

```
    <?php
include( '../conexion.php' );
try {
    function datos_post( $adquirir, $excluir = null ) {
        /* Esta funcion recupera todos los datos pasados por post, tambien se le pueden indicar cuales no se desea recuperar pasandole a la funcion por parametro en el segundo parametro (Puede ser un array) */

        /*
            1- Recuperando todas las claves $_POST eceptuando algunas: (pasados por un array como segundo parametro)
                ------------------------------------------
                $excluir = array('nombre','telefono','email');
                $post = datos_post("ALL",$excluir);
                print_r($post);     
                ------------------------------------------
            2- Recuperando algunas claves $_POST:(solo pasando un array como unico parametro)
                $datos = array('nombre','telefono','email');
                $post = datos_post($datos);
                print_r($post);

                Glosario:

                $adquirir: Es el parametro que se le pasa para obtener datos, con la cadena 'ALL' se obtienen todos los datos

                $excluir: Son los valores que no se desean recuperar.

                */

        $array = array();
        foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
            if ( is_array( $adquirir ) ) {
                if ( in_array( $key, $adquirir ) )$array[ $key ] = $val;
            } elseif ( $adquirir === "ALL" ) {
                if ( isset( $excluir ) ) {
                    if ( is_array( $excluir ) ) {
                        if ( !in_array( $key, $excluir ) )$array[ $key ] = $val;
                    } else {
                        if ( $key != $excluir )$array[ $key ] = $val;

                    }
                } else {
                    $array[ $key ] = $val;
                }
            } else return $_POST[ $adquirir ];
        }
        return $array;
    }


    $post = datos_post( 'ALL' );
    $usuario_que_subio_data = getRealIP();

    /* Establecer validaciones a partir de aqui */


    if(!is_numeric($post['fecha'])){
        if(!$post["fecha"]=="fecha")
            echo "<div>Al parecer el archivo no esta segun las indicaciones</div>";
        exit(0); //Evitar que entren los encabezados de tabla
    }

    $resultado = null;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `unr_data` 
    (DESCRIPCION,PUNTO_DE_SUMINISTRO,FNE,ER_kWh,VER_RD,FNP,Fecha)               
    VALUES
    (:Ndescripcion,:npunto_suministro,:nfne,:ner_kwh,:nver_rd,:nfnp,:nfecha)";

    $resultado = $base->prepare( $sql );

    $resultado->execute( array(
        ":Ndescripcion" => $post[ "descripcion" ],
        ":npunto_suministro" => $post[ "punto_suministro" ],
        ":nfne" => $post[ "fne" ],
        ":ner_kwh" => $post[ "erkwh" ],
        ":nver_rd" => $post[ "verrd" ],
        ":nfnp" => $post[ "fnp" ],
        ":nfecha" => $post[ "fecha" ]
    ) );


        echo("<span style='color:green;font-weight: bold;'>Registros insertados.</span>" );



} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    die( '<span style="color:red;font-size:20px;font-weight: bold;">Error ' . $e->getMessage()."</span>" );
    echo "<span style='color:red;font-size:20px;font-weight: bold;'>Linea del error" . $e->getLine()."</span>";
}
?>
```

Todo funciona perfecto si no fuera por esos caracteres, tengo la codificacion en la base de datos;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual manera esta en la cabecera de mi documento html;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

En la conexion a la base de datos tengo lo siguiente;

```
    <?php

    try{

        $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=unr_dataentry', 'root', '');

        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $base->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");


    }catch (Exception $e){

        die('Error ' . $e->getMessage());
        echo "Linea del error" . $e->getLine();

    }


?>
```

No logro comprender porque no funciona, inclusive inserte manualmente registros en la base de datos y si funciona...

Comment: Añadele al header de la petición ajax: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

Comment: @solamente Sigue igual :/ 
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 include( '../conexion.php' )......

Comment: Si te sigue fallando prueba de hacer el encode HTML antes del envio de información y el decode cuando lo recibas así no tendrias los problemas con los carácteres especiales.

Comment: Por lo que muestra la captura, los datos se insertaron mal en la columna, sea porque: **1.** la fuente desde los tomaste no tenía una codificación adecuada ;  **2.** la columna en sí no tiene una codificación adecuada. Puedes empezar a revisar por la posibilidad 2, verifica que **esa columna** tiene una codificación en utf-8, una vez verificado eso, tienes que corregir uno por uno los datos que se insertaron mal... porque el problema es ese, que los datos se insertaron mal. Cuando tomes fuentes de datos (archivos CSV por ejemplo) para inserciones automáticas, revisa siempre su codificación.